# how to bind jquery with angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Im woking with angular web application . Inside ng-data-view jquery is not working. Please help me to figure out this.

```
$(".jp-playlist").click(function(){
      $(".down").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

this is not working

Comment: stop using jquery in ur angular. :-) This kinda stuff is the job of a directive...

Comment: The question should be 'Why bind jQuery to angular js ?' short answer: there are no good reasons to keep on doing this as jqlite is more than enough and already bound to angular, as stated in the comment above, prefer directives to do this job they are powerful tools.

Comment: While best practice advice can be useful, it's extremely annoying for those who really need this and only find the answer 'Don't do this'. So I hope someone helps him. With that said, OP needs to give more information on what the problem is.

Comment: Post more code (Plunker or JSFiddle would be best) and describe what "is not working"... and ignore 'purists' - they are 100% right but also not very helpfull :-)